# put series of images into one A4 pages using python

Tags: python, image, png

I have a series of graphs (.png files) and I want to put four of them into an A4 page and continue doing this for the rest of my graphs. Is it possible to do it with Python?

Comment: Are you just looking to generate new PNG files where each one is the size of an A4 page at some specified DPI and contains four of the graphs? Or do you actually want to have Python select the A4 bin in your printer, print out the images, and order new ink when it runs low?

Comment: Hi Abarnert, apology for my poor english. I should explain it clearer. I want to do like your first option. Or put a few of my graphs into one pdf page. So I will end up with many pdf pages and each of them contains a few graphs. I've tried to use pdfPages but it only put one image into one pdf page.

Answer (score 6):

If you're just asking how to tile four images together into a larger image, this is easy to do with most image-processing libraries.

I'll show how to do it using PIL/[Pillow](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow):

```
import sys
from PIL import Image

width, height = int(8.27 * 300), int(11.7 * 300) # A4 at 300dpi

images = sys.argv[1:]
groups = [images[i:i+4] for i in range(0, len(images), 4)]
for i, group in enumerate(groups):
    page = Image.new('RGB', (width, height), 'white')
    page.paste(Image.open(group[0]), box=(0, 0))
    page.paste(Image.open(group[1]), box=(int(width/2.+.5), 0))
    page.paste(Image.open(group[2]), box=(0, int(height/2.+.5)))
    page.paste(Image.open(group[3]), box=(int(width/2.+.5), int(height/2.+.5)))
    page.save('page{}.pdf'.format(i))
```

This is meant as sample code, not a complete solution to your problem. A few caveats:

- This generates a separate PDF file for each page.
- I placed the PNG files at the upper-left corner of each quadrant of the page. I don't know where you *want* them placed, but it's probably not exactly that. (Many printers can't print all the way to the margins, and, even if they can, you usually don't want them to.)
- I didn't scale the images, which might be a problem if your graphs are 100x100, or 2000x2000.
- I assumed you wanted to print out at 300dpi.

Comment: THanks! I will try your suggestion

Comment: I had to change the paste to: `page.paste(group[0], box=(0, 0))`